# Passing event and variable to mousemove event handler in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I'm trying to create a drag function using a combination of jQuery mousedown/move/up events, during which I'm trying to pass the starting (cursor) position of the mousedown event to the mousemove event handler but am getting the error

> Argument of type mousemove is not assignable to the type 'PlainObject...'

Here's my code...

```
module controls.draganddrop {

    export function init() {
        $("#mainContent").on("mousedown", ".itemList > ul > li > p", mouseDown);
        $("#mainContent").on("mouseup", ".itemList > ul > li > p", mouseUp);
    }

    function mouseDown(e) {
        var startPosition: object = { x: e.pageX, y: e.pageY };
        $(".itemList > ul > li > p").on("mousemove", mouseMove(event, startPosition));
    }

    function mouseMove(e, startPosition) {
        console.log("pageX: " + e.pageX + ", pageY: " + e.pageY);
    }

    function mouseUp(e) {
        $(".itemList > ul > li > p").off("mousemove", mouseMove);
    }
}
```

The error is on "mousemove" within the mouseDown function. Clearly I've misunderstood something in the jQuery documentation and/or solutions in similar problems, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The duplicate I marked references a click event, but the issue is the same. You're assigning the *returned value* from `mouseMove(event, startPosition)` (ie. `undefined`) to the event handler, not that function itself. You need to wrap that function call in another anonymous function.

Comment: That's certainly resolved the issue, the only problem now is I can't remove the mousemove event handler as it's an anonymous function, is there another way of achieving this?

Comment: I think `$(".itemList > ul > li > p").off("mousemove");` will remove all handlers from `mousemove`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".itemList > ul > li > p").on("mousemove", function(event){ mouseMove(event, startPosition)});
```

Comment: Note that this is unsupported in any version of IE.

Comment: Is there a work-around that is supported in IE?